# stream large data to flowfile in Apache Nifi without OOM

Tags: java, arrays, apache-nifi

I use apache nifi to work with large files. So the output flow file will be large too. How to process this? Maybe use `session.append(byte []);` or use some `/tmpdir` to store. For example, my files are 10Gb, and Processor produces 8Gb, so JVM will fail with `OOM`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the heap size for the JVM to be large enough to handle this (i.e. `-Xmx=20GB` in `bootstrap.conf`). Certainly, a streaming approach will help with that as well. Take a look at existing examples like [`ReplaceText`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ReplaceText.java#L530) to see how streaming is handled.

Comment: No, i mean not to increase java heap to size of max file size

Comment: What processors are you using? Are you trying to write a custom processor?

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Comment: Ok, I provided a link to an existing processor which can stream large files without exhausting the Java heap, so use that as an example.

Comment: Ok, i will see src of it